# Data structure like frozenset which maintains insertion order?

Tags: python, set, immutability, standard-library

I need set-like data structure with these properties:

- hashable
- no duplicate elements
- maintains order
- immutable
- iterable
- part of standard library? want to keep it simple

What is happening:

```
frozenset([3,1,2,2,3]) -> frozenset(1,2,3)
```

What I need:

```
frozenset*([3,1,2,2,3]) -> frozenset*(3,1,2)
```

I thought I could use frozenset but both sets and frozensets
reorder elements. I assume this is for faster duplicate checks?
But in any case I can't have a reordering.

Comment: There is no such data structure in standard library.

Comment: Perhaps just use tuples, and ensure they have no duplicate elements at creation time.

Comment: " both sets and frozensets sort elements" no, they do not. Both of those data structures *have no inherent order*. Anything you see is an implementation detail in this case, most  -- but not all -- integers simply hash to themselves, hence the apparent sorting

Comment: Anyway, what particular aspects of set objects do you require? Is fast-lookup the important part? that is the main set use-case. It sounds like you seem to only care about having no duplicates...

Comment: I stated the properties, however it's fine, i'll mark it as resolved, I figured i'll just use a list and convert it to a string for hashing. I guess i'll ignore the issue with dupicates for now as the code is just for prototyping some solutions and it's just there to ensure the input data is correct.

Comment: @OctaviodelSer well, you mostly stated properties that you *wish* sets had, the only property of sets you mentioned is no duplicates - which is really an ancillary property - and iterable, but if you don't care about, say, the speed of membership testing, then you probably just shouldn't use a set and there are better alternatives. That's my point.

Comment: For example, on Python 3.7+, you could just use tuples and use a function to ensure no duplicates and maintain order (as already alluded to), so just: `def no_dupe(data): return tuple(dict.fromkeys(data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such implementation in the standard library

Comment: correct, but a pity...

Answer (score 4):

As of Python 3.7 dicts no longer reorder elements and instead guarantee to preserve insertion order. You could use a dict where the keys are your set items and the values are ignored.

```
>>> dict.fromkeys([3,1,2,2,3])
{3: None, 1: None, 2: None}
```

Dicts aren't frozen, so if that's crucial then you could first put all the items into a dict and then build a tuple from the keys.

```
>>> tuple(dict.fromkeys([3,1,2,2,3]).keys())
(3, 1, 2)
```

This would be pretty close to a `frozenset`. The main difference is that it would take O(n) rather than O(1) time to check if an item is in the tuple.

Comment: No need to call `.keys`

Comment: Right, it's optional. I prefer to be explicit here. (I'm not a fan of how iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys. One of Python's rare missteps.)